# macOS Ventura 13.1 Always Sleeps on Lock

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, screen-lock, ventura

I'm attempting to lock the screen on my 2021 MacBook Pro (updated to latest OS version, Ventura 13.1 at time of writing) without putting the machine to sleep via **Apple** -> **Lock Screen**. I've attempted the various methods described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450968/is-it-possible-to-explicitly-lock-the-screen-without-ventura-going-to-sleep), [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120639/how-can-i-stop-my-macbook-pro-from-automatically-sleeping-when-i-lock-the-screen?rq=), [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349683/how-to-make-a-macbook-pro-lock-and-not-sleep-when-connected-to-power), and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276338/how-do-i-lock-my-screen-without-making-it-sleep-on-macos-10-11-3). It seems like it should be as simple as:

- **Settings** -> **Displays** -> **Advanced** -> *Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off*
- **Settings** -> **Lock Screen** -> *Turn display off on power adapter when inactive: Never*

What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you determining that the system is asleep?

Comment: @pion There is no longer output to the display, and it takes 20, or so, seconds before the display shows a login, when attempting a wake-up. An interesting side effect is that both bluetooth and wireless USB keyboards take about 10 seconds of continuous input (pressing ESC/Enter/etc) for the wake-up to complete.